# iTerm2 2.0 Unable to resize the main window

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

Ever since I updated to the latest version, my iTerm window is not taking full screen. Even more weird the Maximize/ minimize buttons are missing. This 50% window arrangement is really irritating. I've gone through the preferences and couldn't find anything there.

Am I missing something here?[image: My iTerm2 Window]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was with my settings. Incase someone else is facing the same issue, you can resolve this by going to Preferences -> Profile -> Window :and change the Style to Normal.

Comment: It should also be noted that these settings apply to each window _at the time of it's creation_ only. Since iTerm remembers the window configuration if you exit the app (and restores it on restart), you will need to _close each terminal session_ before exiting iTerm so that new sessions will respect your new profile settings.

Comment: And make sure to close and re-open